# How to check for required parameters in case of JSON type form data

Tags: php

I am using this function to check all required parameters are available or not in request before processing user request.

```
function verifyRequiredParams($required_fields) {
    $error = false;
    $error_fields = "";
    $request_params = array();
    $request_params = $_REQUEST;
    // Handling PUT request params
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        parse_str($app->request()->getBody(), $request_params);
    }
    foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
        if (!isset($request_params[$field]) || strlen(trim($request_params[$field])) <= 0) {
            $error = true;
            $error_fields .= $field . ', ';
        }
    }
    if ($error) {
        // Required field(s) are missing or empty
        // echo error json and stop the app
        $response = array();
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = 'Required field(s) ' . substr($error_fields, 0, -2) . ' is missing or empty';
        echoRespnse(400, $response);
        $app->stop();
    }
}
```

Usage is like this:

```
$app->post('/tasks', function() use ($app) {
    // check for required params
    verifyRequiredParams(array('task'));

    // if OK process request.

});
```

function works fine if post data is of form type. like this: `mobile=1234567880&otp=123456`

Now i am changing the code to accept form data of JSOn type. like this: `{"mobile":"0000000000","otp":"970996", "items":[{"pid":"12", "vid":"20", "pname":"amul"},{"pid":"13", "vid":"2", "pname":"dmul"}]}`

This is how i am getting data.

```
$app->post('/tasks', function() use ($app) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $mobile = $data["mobile"];

    // check for required params
    verifyRequiredParams(array('task'));

    // if OK process request.

});
```

What changes should i do now in `verifyRequiredParams()` to check for required params in case of JSON post data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you don't access PHP superglobals (like `$_REQUEST`) in your verify method. The `verifyRequiredParams` should not really interfere in your application flow, but just verify the parameters and return an appropriate response. Something like this:

```
function verifyRequiredParams($required_fields, $request_params) {
    $error = false;
    $error_fields = array();

    foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
        if (!isset($request_params[$field]) || strlen(trim($request_params[$field])) <= 0) {
            $error = true;
            $error_fields[] = $field;
        }
    }
    if ($error) {
        // Required field(s) are missing or empty
        return array(
            'error' => true,
            'message' => 'Required field(s) ' . implode(', ', $error_fields) . ' is missing or empty'
        );
    }

    // return appropriate response when successful?
    return array(
        'success' => true
    );
}
```

Depending on how your data is being submitted, you pass the appropriate array into the verify method. Here are some examples:

```
// directly pass in the request superglobal (for GET, POST)
$response = verifyRequiredParams(array('task'), $_REQUEST);

// or deal with PUT data
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    parse_str($app->request()->getBody(), $request_params);
    $response = verifyRequiredParams(array('task'), $request_params);
}

// or deal with json encoded data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$response = verifyRequiredParams(array('task'), $data);
```

Since the `verifyRequiredParams` now returns a response, you'll have to deal with this externally, for example:

```
$response = verifyRequiredParams(array('task'), $request_params);
if(isset($response['error'])){
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    echoResponse(400, $response);
    $app->stop();
}
```

Removing superglobals and logic that ties into your application-flow from the validating method will make it easier to reuse.